# How can I add a delay for each moving object?

Tags: unity, c#

The waypoints script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform objectToMovePrefab;
    public int numberOfObjectsToMove = 1;
    //with this approach, you use GameObjects to represent your waypoints 
    //(they can be empty if you want the waypoint to be invisible)
    [SerializeField] private List<Transform> waypoints;

    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjectsToMove; i++)
        {
            var parent = GameObject.Find("Moving Object Parent");
            var objectToMove = Instantiate(objectToMovePrefab, parent.transform);
            objectToMove.name = "Platfrom";
        }
    }

    public int Count => waypoints.Count;
    public Vector3 GetWaypoint(int index)
    {
        return waypoints[index].position;
    }
}
```

Then in the editor I added this script to the prefab :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaypointsFollower : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Waypoints waypoints;
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private bool goBack = false;
    [SerializeField] private float delay;

    private float startTime;
    private int waypointIndex = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        startTime = Time.time + delay;

        waypoints = GameObject.Find("Waypoints").GetComponent<Waypoints>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Time.time < startTime) return;

        Vector3 waypoint = waypoints.GetWaypoint(waypointIndex);
        //movement
        float distance = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoint, distance);

        //check if we've reached the waypoint
        float threshold = .1f; //how close is considered having reached the waypoint
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, waypoint) < threshold)
        {
            //wraps back to 0 when we reach last waypoint
            if (goBack)
            {
                waypointIndex = (waypointIndex + 1) % waypoints.Count;
            }
            else
            {
                if (waypointIndex != waypoints.Count - 1)
                    waypointIndex = waypointIndex + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The delay is working but it's delaying all the WaypointsFollower's so they move at the same time after the delay.

I want that even if all the Followers have the same delay value for example 3 so the first one will start moving after 3 seconds then the next follower will start moving after another 3 seconds and so on and not that they all delay for 3 seconds and move together but to make delay so there will be spaces between the followers when they are moving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:**  are you sure that you set different value of variable ***delay*** for each object/ minion??
Because problem is here: [Time.time](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) is a number of seconds that has passed from **starting the game**. So it will be the same for all objects! So if all minions has variable **delay** set to **3**, and *Time.time* is equal thought the game - means after **3** seconds Time.time+3 will be exactly equal to each object/minion!

**In short, your problem** is that you are counting time from beginning of the game, which is equal to all objects.

**Second:**
When I want to delay something I almost always use [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html). You can specify the time for delay, and since they are asynchronous, so each object can have its own timer running - independent of each other.
Also you can [start](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) Coroutines and [stop](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) them.

Over the time I found that often even more convenient (less code) is [InvokeReapeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)  or just [Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) - you specify time when to fire a function, and that's it. And again each object can have its own timer. You can also [CancelInvoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html) to stop it from firing.

*Update() timers gets **messy***, especially if a lot is happening inside Update() function.

P.S. I do not normally use Update(). In most cases of delays, waypoints, cooldowns, respawns, etc.- *Coroutines* or *InvokeRepeating* or *Invoke* do the job brilliantly, without affecting the rest of the code.

**Here would be example** of code sending different minion every three seconds:
In your main or manager script you write:

```
public List<GameObject> minions = new List<GameObject>();

 void Start()
  {
        InvokeRepeating("SendOneMinion", 3, 3);
  }


int i=0;
public void SendOneMinion()
 {
  if (i< minions.Count && minions[i]!=null)
    minions[i].GetComponent<WaypointsFollower>().GoRightNow();
  else
    CancelInvoke();
   i++;
}
```

Is not that elegant? All you need to do is to add minions to the list. And oh create function GoRightNow() in each minion script..

**Another example with coroutine** even more elegant:

```
public List<GameObject> minions = new List<GameObject>();

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SendOneMinion());
}

private IEnumerator SendOneMinion()
{
    
    foreach (GameObject mn in minions)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        mn.GetComponent<WaypointsFollower>().GoRightNow();
    }
}
```

here coroutine is running, and inside a loop there is 3 second delay before sending new minion..